# jsoup xml parsing - child nodes not displayed

Tags: java, xml, jsoup

I am parsing an xml String. I am able to print only one child.

**My code:**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class RunReport {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String xmlcontent="<Results><ResultSet fetchSize=\"2\">"
                + "<Row rowNumber=\"1\"><TBC_ID>29379155</TBC_ID><TBC_DATE>2013-01-31</TBC_DATE></Row>"
                + "<Row rowNumber=\"2\"><TBC_ID>29379576</TBC_ID><TBC_DATE>2013-01-31</TBC_DATE></Row>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xmlcontent);
        Elements rows =doc.getElementsByTag("Row");
        List<Element> resultSet= doc.getElementsByTag("Row");
        for(int i=0; i<resultSet.size();i++){
            Element RsRecord = resultSet.get(i);
            Elements columns = RsRecord.children();
            for(Element column:columns){
                System.out.println("Row id:"+i+",Column Node name:"+column.nodeName()+",Value="+column.ownText());
            }

        }

    }
```

**Output:**

```
Row id:0,Column Node name:tbc_id,Value=29379155
Row id:1,Column Node name:tbc_id,Value=29379576
```

Tag - 'Row' has two child nodes, but my output shows only one child.

**Expected:**

```
Row id:0,Column Node name:tbc_id,Value=29379155
Row id:0,Column Node name:tbc_date,Value=2013-01-31
Row id:1,Column Node name:tbc_id,Value=29379576
Row id:1,Column Node name:tbc_date,Value=2013-01-31
```

Comment: Close <Results><ResultSet fetchSize=\"2\"> otherwise the xml is malformed.

Comment: @MissingSemiColon, Thanks for sharing the info. I will add those tags and update my observation here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
package test;

import java.util.List;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class RunReport {

public static void main(String[] args){
    String xmlcontent="<Results>"
            + "<ResultSet fetchSize=\"2\">"
            + "<data rowNumber=\"1\">"
            + "<a>29379155</a>"
            + "<b>2013-01-31</b>"
            + "</data>"
            + "<data rowNumber=\"2\">"
            + "<a>29379576</a>"
            + "<b>2013-01-31</b>"
            + "</data>"
            + "</Results>"
            + "</ResultSet>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xmlcontent);
    List<Element> resultSet = doc.getElementsByTag("data");
    for(int i=0; i<resultSet.size();i++){
        Element RsRecord = resultSet.get(i);
        Elements columns = RsRecord.children();
        for(Element column:columns){
            System.out.println("Row id:"+i+",Column Node name:"+column.nodeName()+",Value="+column.ownText());
        }

    }

}
}
```

My guess is that you are using a reserved work in your xml. When i use your code this is the structure printed for me:

```
<row rownumber="1">
 <tbc_id>
  29379155
  <tbc_date>
   2013-01-31
   <row rownumber="2">
    <tbc_id>
     29379576
     <tbc_date>
      2013-01-31
     </tbc_date>
    </tbc_id>
   </row>
  </tbc_date>
 </tbc_id>
</row>
<row rownumber="2">
 <tbc_id>
  29379576
  <tbc_date>
   2013-01-31
  </tbc_date>
 </tbc_id>
</row>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am unable to upvote as I am getting this error `Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Don't worry glad I could help and I learned something new too.